# Can't simulate holding a key in python

Tags: python, keyboard, pyautogui

i'm trying to make a python script that simulates holding down keys using pyautogui or keyboard, but i just can't manage to make it really hold down the key. Instead of typing zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz it types z. If anyone could help me that would be great if possible please use keyboard or pyautogui library but if not i'm willing to learn another library. Thank you all in advance.

with pyautogui.hold("z"):
#anything

result: z
expected: zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a common problem, usually it has something to do with how you are testing it.

Take this for an example:

```
import pyautogui
import time

pyautogui.keyDown('z') #is supposed to hold the key 'z' down
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.keyUp('z') #is supposed to release the key 'z'
```

Usually what happens is the output is: "z". And that's to be expected. `Pyautogui` actually is pressing the key down, the output is the problem. Normally, when a user presses and holds a key down, the key is repeatedly typed, so you get output: "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz". But in this case, for some reason, `pyautogui` holds the key down, but does not type it repeatedly. It is, however, holding the key down (at least in my case).

To test that it is really holding the key down, open up a web browser application (or whatever, something that requires pressing keys), I used a simple web browser game that needed the key "w" to be pressed sometimes. I wrote a simple `pyautogui` program to hold the key w down, and tested it in the web browser game, and it worked, so at least in my case, **the key was being held down**. Do this same test to figure it out.

If you truly wanted the output: "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz", then you could just use `pyautogui's typewrite()' function, to type the letters out in the shell. But I'm guessing that your original purpose was to hold the key down, so run the same test I did, and figure out if the key is being held down.